# swagger-ui how to form multiple responses in schema array

Tags: json, rest, swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

I am trying to form a swagger document in this format. The response is the below json on 200 http code. I am unable to form a json like below.

```
[
  {
    "key":"test1", 
    "val":"val1" 
  },
  {
    "key":"test2", 
    "val":"val2" 
  },
  {
    "key":"test3", 
    "val":"val3" 
  }
]
```

so far I have this:

```
"responses": {
                    "200": {
                        "description": "response",
                        "schema": {
                            "type": "array",
                            "items": {
                                "$ref": "#/definitions/res1",
                                "$ref": "#/definitions/res2"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

 "definitions": {
    "res1": {
                    "type": "object",
                    "properties": {
                            "key": {
                                    "type": "string",
                                    "example": "test1"
                            },
                            "keyURL": {
                                    "type": "string",
                                    "example": "val1"
                            }
                        }
                },
                "res2": {
                    "type": "object",
                    "properties": {
                            "key": {
                                    "type": "string",
                                    "example": "test2"
                            },
                            "val": {
                                    "type": "string",
                                    "example": "val2"
                            }
                        }
                }
```

But I dont see the `res2` block at all. I just see `res1`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JSON pointers (`$ref`) must live "alone" in an object.  Thus you cannot have multiple pointers in your `items` block:

```
  "$ref": "#/definitions/res1",
  "$ref": "#/definitions/res2"
```

will ignore the 2nd reference (`res2`) and only apply the first.

For what you're trying to do, you have many options.  Probably the easiest is something like this:

```
type: array
items:
  $ref: '#/definitions/Pair'
```

and having definitions like such:

```
definitions:
  Pair:
    properties:
      key:
        type: string
      value:
        type: string
```